# axios / request used for schema / model

Tags: javascript, request, schema, axios

I want to build a db of users and if they have a site check if the site is online save the url if not delete it and advise the user that the site is offline. The problem is when the program goes thru the request it seems to do nothing and just jumps out, I tried using axios and request but the problem still remains; I believe it might be due to asynchronous computations. Any help will be really appreciated =)

```
var r = require('rethinkdb');
var axios = require('axios');

var schema = function(data, callback){
  new_schema = true;
  var schema = {};
  if(new_schema){
    schema.user = user.id;
  }

  schema.name = data.title || '';
  schema.email = data.email || '';

  if(data.url){
    axios.get(data.url).then(function(err, response){
     if(err) schema.url = 'no site'  
     schema.url = 'data.url';
     callback(schema);
    }).catch(function(error){
       console.log(error);
      callback(schema);
     });
  }else{
    callback(schema);
  }

};
  var datos = '';  
  command.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    datos = datos + data;
  });


  command.on('close', (code) => {

      const objs = JSON.parse(datos);
      for (var i in objs) {
        let obj = schema(objs[i], function(sch){
          console.log(sch);
        });
      }
    }catch(e){
      console.log(e);
    }
    process.exit();
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to the asynchronous. To solved it had to use queues and I used the library better-queue. This fix the problem and makes all the calls to the server side.